# iterating through a changing list with Linq

Tags: linq, primes

I'm trying to find the prime number in a list using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). I tried this:

```
var primeNumber = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(2, max - 1));
primeNumber.ForEach(m => primeNumber.RemoveAll(n => n % m == 0));
```

but it didn't work since you can't iterate on a list which is changing. 
Is there a better way than creating another array and iterating trough it since I only need to iterate trough prime number? With the second array, I would remove everything which can be divided by 2 and then remove everything which can be divided by 4 (there should be none) and so on.

Comment: Don't use lists for the Sieve of Eratosthenes, use bit arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to do it that way :

```
double maxFactor = Math.Sqrt(primeNumber.Max());
while (factor <= maxFactor) 
{ 
    factor = primeNumber.First(n => n > factor);
    primeNumber.RemoveAll(n => n != factor && n % factor == 0);
}
```

It's working and still pretty fast and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just copy the numbers to a new array and do the `ForEach` on that. I don't think that there is a better way.